# Find a commutative ring $R$ (with $1$) such that $R$ has a proper ideal $I$ which is prime but not maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

let, $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and then we let $I = (x)$, the ideal generated by $x$. Let, $ab \in (x)$, then $\deg(a) + \deg(b) \ge 1$, which implies $\deg(a)$ or $\deg(b)$ are greater than or equal to $1$; hence, $a \in I$ or $b \in I$. We have that,
$I \subset (2,x),$
since $I$ does not contain $2$.

Does my proof look good? Any issues? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe writing $I\subsetneq (2,x)$ is better notation.

Comment: In addition to the perceptive answer given by Lost in Space, to complete your argument, it would also be necessary to show that $(2,X) \neq R$. Otherwise, $I \subset (2,X)$ does not necessarily imply non-maximality.

Comment: $1\notin (x, 2) $ . It's trivial

Comment: @LostinSpace 1) it's not *super* trivial, 2) even if it was, it is worth mentioning.

Comment: $(x, 2) $ contains all polynomial with even constant terms. Not all polynomials have this feature. It's trivial.

Comment: @LostinSpace But still worth mentioning, even if it is stated without justification.

Comment: I assumed this as trivial because op already mentioned in the post about the ideal $(x, 2) $. So i belive op can prove it's a proper ideal. Otherwise it's a good exercise to make it trivial.

Comment: @legionwhale Feel free to edit my answer to provide more details if you want.

Comment: @LostinSpace My comment was never a criticism of your answer. Your answer is concise and provides all of the relevant information. I was only reminding OP that it would be better to remark on this fact when writing a proof (as that's what they said they were doing). Apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @legionwhale You have made no mistake. Don't need to feel sorry. If you wish, you can edit my answer to look better. I know "trivial" is a very dangerous word. But it will be a good exercise for the readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p\in (x) $ implies the constant term of $p$ is zero.

By proving $\deg(a) \ge 1$ is not sufficient to conclude that $a\in (x) $

$pq\in (x) $ implies $p(x) q(x) =xh(x) $ for some $h(x) \in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ .

Then the constant term of $p(x) q(x) $ is zero implies at least one polynomial $p$ or $q$ has constant term $0$ . Hence $p$ or $q$ one of them must be in $(x) $

---

Alt:  $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ with $1$. Then

1. $I$ is prime iff ${R}/{I}$ is an
   integral domain.
2. $I$ is maximal iff ${R}/{I}$ is a field.

$\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x) \cong \Bbb{Z}$

Hence $(x) $ is prime but not maximal.

---

Comment: Also note that $(0)\subset\mathbb Z$ is already an example.

Comment: Exactly $(0) $ is prime in $R$  iff R is ID. It's an equivalent definition of ID

Comment: @KentaS, I wanted an example that was not "trivial" and not "overtly complex" as the others one I have seen on stack exchange.